# Link submit button to another page

Tags: php, html

I want to link a submit button to another PHP page. But using *action* in form *tag* doesn't allow the PHP code that comes next to be executed. I don't get the variable $_SESSION['logged']'s value to be 1. Is it because the page directly goes to the "messages.php" before the whole code is executed?

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html  >
<body class="main">
    <form action="messages.php" method="post">
        <p><center>Username : <input type="text" name="user" class="form-control"/></center></p>
        <p><center>Password : <input type="password" name="pswd" class="form-control"/></center></p>
        <p><center><input type="submit"  value="Log in" class="btn btn-primary"/></center></p>
        </div>
    </form>
<?php
$_SESSION['logged']=0;
$_SESSION['user'] = '';
$_SESSION['pswd'] = '';

if (isset($_POST['user']) AND isset($_POST['pswd']) )
{
    $user=$_POST['user'];
    $pswd=$_POST['pswd'];
    $account = new Account();
    try {
        $logged = $account->LogIn($user, $pswd);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        /* Something went wrong: echo the exception message and die */
        echo $e->getMessage();
        die();
    }
    $_SESSION['logged']=1; #1 means logged in
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post to the same page, redirect to `messages.php` when everything is set/there are no errors

Comment: Unrelated: `<center>` is deprecated! `</div>` can be removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form should be with the action on the page you are making the logic, which means the present one:

```
<form action="?" method="post">
            <p><center>Username : <input type="text" name="user" class="form-control"/></center></p>
            <p><center>Password : <input type="password" name="pswd" class="form-control"/></center></p>
            <p><center><input type="submit"  value="Log in" class="btn btn-primary"/></center></p>
        </div>
        
        </form>
```

And then, after applying busines logic redirect to messages.php:

```
    <?php

$_SESSION['logged']=0;

$_SESSION['user'] = '';
$_SESSION['pswd'] = '';

if (isset($_POST['user']) AND isset($_POST['pswd']) )
{
    $user=$_POST['user'];
    $pswd=$_POST['pswd'];


$account = new Account();
try
{
    $logged = $account->LogIn($user, $pswd);
    $_SESSION['logged']=1; #1 means logged in

$script = "<script>
window.location = 'messages.php';</script>";
echo $script;


}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    /* Something went wrong: echo the exception message and die */
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}


}

?>
```